# Trying to browse to a new web root in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

OK, the documentation says:

> If you configure the folder containing FW/1 as a new web root and
>   browse to it, you'll see an introductory application.

So I created a new site in Windows Vista and pointed it to the Framework 1 bundle.
I've installed CF10, and am able to navigate to http://localhost:8500/CFIDE/administrator/

so I know that's working.
But when I navigate to http://localhost/, it gives me:

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Requested URL   http://localhost:80/
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\seancorfield-fw1-9e69741
```

And trying localhost:8500 goes to C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot
[image: Visa Framework1]

Comment: What about your port in localhost for browsing the root??

Comment: J.T.: Trying localhost:8500 goes to C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote up a pretty detailed blog post here:

http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2012/02/changing-webroot-of-coldfusion-zeus.html

It looks like you may not have updated your mapping to the WEB-INF and CFIDE folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it as the built in server then it will be 8500.

If you integrated into IIS then it will be port 80

You may just need to run the web connector tool, you will find it in the start menu.

If that doesnt work, you likely don't have the necessary bits of IIS installed.

Comment: Dale, I don't see a web connector tool on my Vista machine.

Comment: Start, All Programs, Adobe, ColdFusion 10, Web Server Configuration Tool